# are there any downsides to using Google Font API?

Tags: css, web, font-face, google-font-api

I am pretty sure my site wont work with IE6, do not care.
I am looking for technical problems, Like slow,service is down many times etc.
I am not looking for subjective issues like "they have only lousy fonts" etc.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that visitors from China, Iran and North Korea will have a tough time viewing your site if you're pulling fonts (or anything) from Google.

Their connection will likely time-out.

Apart from that, I've not noticed any issues at all. In fact I'd heartily recommend it over any other font provider. It can be done asynchronously too if you use Google loader

Answer (score 1):

Actually internet explorer was the first browser to implement the @font-face attribute so it should work down to IE5. Really the only downsides are a little extra bandwidth and a somewhat limited selection of fonts, but the google font library has grown to be fairly large.

Google has a lot of servers all over the world, it's doubtful that their service would really ever be down.